# Css file is not linked to html page in Github

Tags: html, css, git, github, web

hello I am uploading my html and css files to github and they are linked by

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
```

but then I open the site I can't see the css effects they are not applied what can I do
this is the site

https://keycode14.github.io/My-Assignment/module2-solution/

I tried every video on youtube but it didn't help

Comment: Everything look correct. What is the actual problem?

Comment: When I visit the link the `css.css` file loads correctly, no errors in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I see that styles that are wrote in `CSS` file are applied.
One thing that you can try is **to clear browser cache**: Sometimes, the browser may cache older versions of the `CSS` file, preventing the changes from being reflected.
Clear your browser cache **or try** opening the website in an **incognito/private** browsing window to bypass the cache.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).